# Tensorflow indexing

Tags: python, indexing, tensorflow

I would like to choose a tensor by range of rows with all columns.

Something like:

```
x[10:20,:]
```

Rows 10 to 20 with all columns.

I have tried to use:

```
tf.gather_nd
```

What is the way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tensorflow supports numpy style indexing: `x[10:20,:]`.

An example:

```
 x = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(100, 100)))
 y = x[10:20,]

 sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
 tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
 y.eval().shape
 #output
 #(10, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [tf.slice](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice)

So assuming you have a 2D tensor as your example seems to indicated, to get 10:20 of the first dimension you would do:
`tf.slice(x, begin = [10,0], size = [10, x.get_shape().as_list()[1]])`

Note: `begin` is 0 indexed and and `size` is 1 indexed. So the size I put will give you dimension 1 of length 10 from starting/begin point and all of dimension 2.